# Copy files to directory with random name with batch

Tags: batch-file, deployment, cmd, scripting, firefox-addon

I'm trying to Deploy/copy an extension for Firefox to all of my Windows computers.

The only location which allows Auto Updates is in: %appdata%\Mozilla\Profiles\
"Profile_Name"\Extensions.

The problem is that although no one uses profiles, the "Default" Profile have a random prefix name (62x8awd89.default \ 46wx5awd.default).

How can I copy the file to the ****.default/Extension Folder via batch script?

Comment: I know [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43398315/6738015) isn't a verified answer but it may get you each of your users profile paths regardless whether default or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to parse your question but I think this gets you close:

```
for /D %%D in ("%appdata%\Mozilla\Profiles\*.default") do copy file.dat "%%D\Extensions"
```